# Каждые/каждую пару километров

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, будьте добры: *каждые/каждую пару километров.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Корректный вариант:  ***каждую пару километров.***

***Пара*** — это грамматическое существительное, не числительное, хотя может использоваться как счетное слово в разговорной речи:

ПАРА, -ы; ж. [нем. Paar] 7. **Разг.** Счётное слово, обозначающее два (обычно в розничной торговле). Купить пару яблок. Мне пару пива, пожалуйста (две кружки, бутылки). // Разг. **Небольшое количество чего-л., несколько**. Я отвлеку вас на пару минут. Поживи у нас пару дней. Мы с ним виделись пару раз.

Несочетаемость по роду и числу (***каждые пару*** километров) для стоящих рядом слов выглядит **некорректно.**  Поэтому даже с учетом разных семантических оттенков следует предпочесть грамматически правильное сочетание.

В нацкорпусе есть только один пример с использованием мн. числа:   *Так арабы **через каждые пару километров** напаяли на дороги по «лежачему полицейскому».*  [Алексей Буданов.  2003]

В данном случае более уместным было бы выражение ***через каждые два километра***.

Answer (score 2):

В обоих исходных вариантах есть некоторое противоречие между определённостью (каждые) и неопределённостью ("пара" в таком контексте мало чем отличается от "пары-тройки" или "нескольких"). Этим можно пренебречь, если акцент делается не на количестве. Тогда выбор зависит от переходности глагола по отношению к этому сочетанию:

> Каждые пару километров они останавливались и делали передышку.
>
> Каждую пару километров (лучше: **каждые два километра**) они отмечали
>   на карте своим цветом.

Answer (score 0):

*Кажд**ую** пару километров* — что-то сделать с этой парой:
*пометить флажками каждую пару километров;

качественно проложить каждую пару километров асфальта;

отметить на карте каждую пару километров*.

*Кажд**ые** пару километров* — что-то сделать за период преодолевания этого расстояния:
*Каждые пару километров они делали привал.

Каждые пару километров они садились передохнуть.*